# Saving the state of a movieclip containing multiple movieclips inside

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, save, movieclip

this is actually a noobish question, but is there a possible way to save a certain state of a movieclip?, example i dynamically added a movieclip called big_mc, then inside big_mc contains three(3) smaller movie called child_mc1 and child_mc2 and a close_big to remove big_mc from the stage, when i click either of child_mc1 and child_mc2, the child_mc will disappear prior to which child_mc i clicked.

so the scenario is when I click child_mc1 which remove itself from the scene, then next I'll click the close_big movieclip to remove big_mc from the stage and will save it's own state, so then the next time i run the SWF file and dynamically add big_mc to stage, child_mc1 would be still missing and child_mc2 would still be displayed (EVEN IF I CLOSE THE SWF FILE, the state should be saved). please help..much is appreciated.

code in main time line:

```
    var big_mc:mother_mc = new mother_mc;

    add_big_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, call_big);

    function call_big(e:MouseEvent):void
    {
            addChild(big_mc);
    }
```

the code inside big_mc:

```
    child_mc1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, remove_child1);
    child_mc2.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, remove_child2);
    close_big.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, bye);


    function remove_child1(e:MouseEvent):void
    {
            removeChild(child_mc1);
    }

    function remove_child2(e:MouseEvent):void
    {
            removeChild(child_mc2);
    }

    function bye(e:MouseEvent):void
    {
            this.parent.removeChild(this);
    }
```

Comment: Saving a swf's states is a fairly hefty task. You're best off finding a specific tutorial or article about that subject.

Answer (score 0):

You want to start with [SharedObject](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/SharedObject.html), which as Adobe puts it, "is used to read and store limited amounts of data on a user's computer or on a server". To save the "state" of the MovieClip is more complicated.

What about it do you want to save?  The x property?  Perhaps the alpha? EVERYTHING?  Each object is stored in a default state in your swf.  Library items in the Flash IDE are technically miniature classes, as evidenced by the way we instantiate them.  Assuming you create something called `customButton`, you could spawn thousands of them onscreen (or one) like this:

```
var foo:customButton = new customButton();
```

Like a hand-written class, a copy of the `customButton` is created with all the properties you defined on it before you compiled it.  If you want to change those properties, you have to address each and every one you want different.

Looking at this broadly, let's assuming you want to save the position of your button every time you load the swf.  Load with [getLocal()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/SharedObject.html#getLocal%28%29), and save with [flush()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/SharedObject.html#flush%28%29).

```
var settings:Object = SharedObject.getLocal("foo");

function updateState(e:Event):void {
    myButton.x = settings.x;
    myButton.y = settings.y;
} 

function saveState():void {
    settings.x = myButton.x;
    settings.y = myButton.y;
    settings.flush();
}
```

It's not impossible; there's simply no push-button solution for it.  If you wanted, you could write a function which iterates over all DisplayObjects, and loads/saves each relavent property from/into your SharedObject.  Might be overkill, though.

Comment: i went to do some little research on "sharedObjects", and thank you for that, but i still dont have any idea on how to save the state of big_mc, im kinda confused on what property of big_mc to use to save inside the sharedobject..

Comment: There is no state saving.  You have to do it manually, by hand.  If you want to save the visible state of your MovieClips, save to the `SharedObject` some sort of identifier, like `mc1:Boolean = false; mc2:Boolean = true`, and when you read the `SharedObject` into memory, and see those values, you know you need to (in addition to creating the MovieClips as you normally would) hide/show each appropriately.